# Can the memory use of Hadoop/Yarn be measured from within spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running a long-lived spark job on AWS EMR using Yarn as the resource manager. After running for a while, some of the nodes stop responding, and looking at Ganglia I can see that we have run out of memory.

[image]

Once this happens, the application is killed and the memory is recovered. However, If I try to monitor the memory using: `sc.getExecutorStorageStatus()[executor].memUsed()` and `sc.getExecutorStorageStatus()[executor].memRemaining()`, the system reports that only 140Mb of the 25Gb is being used (right before the crash). Looking on the EMR cluster itself, it appears the `hadoop` and `yarn` processes are the ones consuming the resources.

Is there a way to programmatically determine the resources utilized by Yarn during the runtime of a Spark application?

Comment: Are you summing across all running executors?

Comment: This graph is one executor, but the cluster shows a similar pattern, the memory for the cluster is approaching 100% and then the nodes start failing. I would like to get something like an array of memory usage from Hadoop Yarn, with an element for each executor.

Comment: We can use listeners for example  
 https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/scheduler/StatsReportListener.html , inside listener use yarn rest api https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html

Comment: The graph looks like one host. A host can hold many executor processes